# Iterating through object with `Object.keys().forEach()` changes value type

Tags: javascript, object, iteration

Consider the following example code:

```
let obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, val){
    console.log(typeof val);    //returns: number
});

console.log(typeof obj['a']);   //returns: string
```

I find this behaviour very interesting. Why does it do this? I assume this has something to do with JavaScript in certain situations auto-parsing variables (such as concatenating a number to a string) and the passing of said variable to a callback function.

I am also curious if there is a simple way of preserving the original value type? I know you could force a particular type but it there a way to have it stay a number or a string based on what was originally passed short of adding a variable that would then be set to the variable type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First argument in forEach is a value, second is index of array

```
let obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, index){
  console.log(typeof index);    //returns: number
  console.log(typeof key);      //returns: string
});

console.log(typeof obj['a']);   //returns: string
```

Answer (score 8):

The callback for [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is given three arguments, the current value, the index, and the array itself. `val` is the second argument (which should really be given a more appropriate name), so it is the index, which is a number.

This may help you understand:

```js
let obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, idx, arr){
    console.log("Key:", key);
    console.log("Index:", idx);
    console.log("Original Array:", arr);
    console.log("Value:", obj[key]);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to directly access values (with destructuring):

```js
let obj = {a: '1', b: '2'};

Object.entries(obj).forEach(function([key, val], idx, arr){
    console.log("Key:", key);
    console.log("Index:", idx);
    console.log("Original Array:", arr);
    console.log("Value:", val);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

`val` is just a foreach iterator index number. You need to use `obj[key]` to get the value